# Angular and anchor tag to external url not working

Tags: angular

I cannot get a simple link to work in angular.  If I put this in the app component outside of any other components it works.  the minute I put it inside a child component it does not work.  I click on it and nothing happens.  I can right click and do open in another tab but clicking does nothing.  No errors either.

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">google</a>
```

Comment: Can you show more of the code in the component?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out a component higher up in my app tree had a click event with $event.preventDefault.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<a target="blank" type="button"  href="{{hrefLink}} (click)="toLink()"></a>
```

in your component put

```
toLink() {
     hrefLink = 'http://www.google.com';
}
```